# Detect high variability of signal

Tags: python, signals, signal-processing

I have a signal that alternate between a high values and low values. Now I want to detect the window where there is a higher variability of the signal to detect abnormal behavior of the system. How can I do that with `Python` ?

**EDIT:**

I think that the problem would be solved if I have a function that returns a frequency estimation over a set of data (sample/window of the signal).

Comment: Well, you probably should take a look on wavelets anomaly detection techniques. [Here]( http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/942) for a start.